# index.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined

Tags: javascript, javascript-import, swiper.js

I am not quite familiar with using import/export but I am trying to learn it. Now I am facing a problem.

I have two JS files, core.js and index.js. Core is used on every page, index on home page. When I import swiper in core.js I assume that I can also use it in index.js but it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
index.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined.
```

When I copy and paste the import statement from core.js into index.js it works but I don't think that is the correct solution because of the duplicate imports + extra file size for index.js. Can anyone help me out?

core.js

```
import Swiper from 'swiper/bundle';
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';

const uspSlider = new Swiper('.uspSlider', {
    centeredSlides: true,
    slidesPerView: 1.5,
    spaceBetween: 15,
    loop: true,
    speed: 2500,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 0,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    breakpoints: {
        992: {
            centeredSlides: false,
            autoplay: {
                delay: 1000,
                disableOnInteraction: true,
            },
            slidesPerView: 4,
            loopedSlides: 5,

        }
    }
});
```

index.js

```
const slider = new Swiper('.projectSlider', {
    autoplay: {
        delay: 2500,
    },
    speed: 500,
    centeredSlides: true,
    loop: true,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    slidesPerView: 1.3,
    breakpoints: {
        992: {
            centeredSlides: false,
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 30,
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You also have to import in index.js

Comment: @user2258152 but this will result in larger file size, right? Is this the only solution?

Comment: Use webpack https://webpack.js.org/ or parcel https://parceljs.org/ to avoid this. It will bundle all your code into one optimized js file that you can reference on each page. Now if you also want to avoid using script tag on each page you need to use react or any other single app framework.